# debug in swift: I not find error in cod

Tags: swift, swift2

> ---------- ERROR IS: 2016-07-31 11:16:36.116 t6_TableDemo[900:25064] -[UIView tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7feaa273c520 2016-07-31 11:16:36.326
>   t6_TableDemo[900:25064] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIView
>   tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7feaa273c520'
>   *** First throw call stack: (

---

And Code is:

```
{
//

//  ViewController.swift

//  t6_TableDemo

//

//  Created by dvd shd on 7/29/16.

//  Copyright © 2016 zohur. All rights reserved.

//


import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {


    let devcourses=[("ios App","simon All" ),("ios 8","Biotifull"),("Win 7"," it is good"), ("Windows 8","is a bad"), ("Linux 7","is better"), ("ios 9","verry very Good"),("Xcode 7","it is better")]



    let webcourses=[("rghamsar","akhavan" ),("azmadar","bakhshali"),("rezapedar","shokrollahzadeh"), ("mohammadhoseinfarzand","shokrollahzadeh"), ("zhkhahar","shokrollahzadeh"), ("pakhahar","shokrollahzadeh"),("khodam","it is better")]






    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2

    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {





        if section == 0 {

            return devcourses.count

        } else

        {

            return webcourses.count

        }



    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as UITableViewCell









        if indexPath.section == 0 {

             let (courseTitle,courseAuthor)=devcourses[indexPath.row]

             cell.textLabel?.text=courseTitle

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = courseAuthor





        }

        else {

            let (courseTitle,courseAuthor)=webcourses[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text=courseAuthor

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text=courseTitle

        }

       // Retrieve in image

        var myImage = UIImage(named: "CellIcon")

        cell.imageView?.image=myImage



        return cell

    }





    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0 {

            return "Developer Courses"

         } else

        {

            return "Web Courses"

        }

    }







    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {

        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.

    }



}



}
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed 2 things in your project.

1: Create an `@IBOutlet` for your `tableView`.

2: Conform its `dataSource` in your `viewDidLoad` method and your result will be:

[image]

Complete code will be:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource {


    let devcourses=[("ios App","simon All" ),("ios 8","Biotifull"),("Win 7"," it is good"), ("Windows 8","is a bad"), ("Linux 7","is better"), ("ios 9","verry very Good"),("Xcode 7","it is better")]

    let webcourses=[("rghamsar","akhavan" ),("azmadar","bakhshali"),("rezapedar","shokrollahzadeh"), ("mohammadhoseinfarzand","shokrollahzadeh"), ("zhkhahar","shokrollahzadeh"), ("pakhahar","shokrollahzadeh"),("khodam","it is better")]

    @IBOutlet weak var tblView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        tblView.dataSource = self
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 2

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if section == 0 {

            return devcourses.count

        } else {

            return webcourses.count

        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as UITableViewCell

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            let (courseTitle,courseAuthor)=devcourses[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text=courseTitle

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = courseAuthor

        }

        else {

            let (courseTitle,courseAuthor)=webcourses[indexPath.row]

            cell.textLabel?.text=courseAuthor

            cell.detailTextLabel?.text=courseTitle

        }

        // Retrieve in image

        let myImage = UIImage(named: "CellIcon")

        cell.imageView?.image=myImage

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {

        if section == 0 {

            return "Developer Courses"

        } else {

            return "Web Courses"

        }
    }
}
```

Check [Demo Project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=50699195746437696197) for more Info.